# Proving $S = \{Ax | x \in\Bbb R^n\}$ is closed under addition.

Tags: linear-transformations

> To show that $S = \{Ax | x \in\Bbb R^n\}$, is closed under addition,

Is it enough to say the following?

Let $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ be in $\Bbb R^n$. Then $\vec u + \vec v\in\Bbb R^n$. Therefore $A(\vec u) + A(\vec v) = A(\vec u+\vec v)$ and $S$ is closed under addition.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You solution is correct.

Comment: I'd phrase it slightly differently. Let $ w, z\in S $. Then there exist $ x, y \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $ w = Ax $ and $ z= Ay $. Thus $ w+z= Ax + Ay = A (x + y) $. This shows that $w+z\in S $.  Hence $ S $ is closed under addition.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is fine. Since it looks like an exercise on the fundamentals of linear maps, remember to mention it in your proof when you use linearity:

Since $A$ is a linear map, we have that $A(u+v) = A(u) + A(v)$ for all $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$.